# Amazon SES aws for not existent/wrong gmail address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Something odd is happening and I am wondering what is the explanation.
I have a web application which is using amazon SES to send email when users lose passwords, on new registrations, etc...
While testing I realized SES is returning a "500 BAD REQUEST" for specific email address, I typed pippo@gmail.com just to test the UI of my application perfectly knowing the email address does not exist, and I got "500 BAD REQUEST", initially I could not understand what was wrong so I kept debugging and not understanding why error 500; later I realized I was getting it for not existent or generic email address.
For example if I try sending email to "bar@gmail.com" I get the 500, but if I try "foo@gmail.com" I do not.
(By the way for an italian pippo@gmail.com is equivalent to foo@gmail.com)

If I try with pippo@hotmail.com, foo@hotmail.com, bar@hotmail.com, I don't have any issue.

Actually this could be a feature, maybe it is and I just didn't know.

Is SES behaving like that for anyone else?

Comment: SES has 2 modes, one for testing and one for production.  Are you in the production mode?

Comment: I am in production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SES blacklists email addresses that bounce. When you try to send an email, it makes sure that the address is not blacklisted (that is, it did not bounce recently).

My guess is that those addresses are so commonly used by people testing SES that they almost always bounce and so they get blacklisted.